# Dataset with common dialogues

Tags: data-request, social-media, text

I'm looking for datasets with people's dialogues, just everyday communication.

Example:

> How are you?
>   Fine, thank you, and how are you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general list of data repositories:

- [Towards Data Science Repository](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-data-lakes-worth-of-audio-datasets-b45b88cd4ad)
- [15 Best Chatbot Datasets for Machine Learning](https://gengo.ai/datasets/15-best-chatbot-datasets-for-machine-learning/)
- [Artificial Intelligence Wiki - Open Data Sets](https://skymind.ai/wiki/open-datasets)
- [Reddit - Machine Learning - Datasets of One to One Conversations](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3ukvc6/datasets_of_one_to_one_conversations/)
- [A Survey of Available Corpora for Building Data-Driven Dialogue Systems](https://breakend.github.io/DialogDatasets/)

Comment: Please fix the layout of your answer, name and describe the datasets. Currently this is just a [link only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) which risks getting deleted

Comment: @Jan Doggen, later i 'll do it.